# How can I pass a string from main class to another class using TestNG in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have 2 classes, 1 is test class for running testng code and another is main class. I want to pass string value from main class to test class for running testng code. Please help me to execute main class.

**main class code :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[]{
                 packagename.classname.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
 }
```

**testng class code :**

```
Select product_name_dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("")));
product_name_dropdown.selectByVisibleText(product_name);
```

I want to pass value of **product_name** variable from main class to testng class.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Or you write a proper test and don't do what you're asking here? Write tests which don't require any input and test specific situations.

Comment: I want to create jar with argument and I will pass **product_name** by parameter like dynamic value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You have to use the `setParameters(Map<String,String params)` method of `XmlSuite or XmlTest` class to pass parameters*.

```
Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
param.put("name", "CrazyForSure");
suite.setParameters(param);
```

And annotate your Test method with this parameter using `@Parameters`.